# NoMemoryError in Array#max

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I'm working on a codewars problem to parse an integer and re-order its digits in descending order. My working solution is below; I decided to use string methods to quickly parse the digits (instead of mods or log_10s):

```
# descending_order : int => int
# Takes an int, re-orders its digits in descending order, and returns that

# ex. descending_order(1234) => 4321

def descending_order(n)
  n.to_s.chars.sort.reverse.join.to_i
end
```

However, when playing around with the solution, I also tried the following variation, which threw a `NoMemoryError` for a reasonably small input:

```
def descending_order(n)
  n.to_s.chars.max(n).join.to_i
end
```

yields:

```
descending_order(456454576895645)
NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
from (pry):129:in `max'
```

Clearly, `sort` is the proper way to sort an array over `max(<array_length>)`, but I'm curious about why `max` is hogging so much memory here. What leads to this behavior, and do I need to be careful with similar situations (e.g. taking max(20) off an array of 100 integers)?

Comment: You're not doing `max(array_length)`, you're doing `max(n)`. Also as a side note [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-digits) may also be of interest.

Comment: That's a really cool feature for Ruby 2.4! I'm in Ruby 2.3, where the Integer class isn't implemented, but I look forward to using that. Also, got it: n is going to be trying to make a very big array there!

Comment: @DavidBodow fun fact: `[].max(2**60)` raises `ArgumentError: array size too big` and `[].max(2**70)` raises ``RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'``. The `NoMemoryError` however looks very strange. My Ruby version even shows debugging information like `*** error: can't allocate region`. I think you should file a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk).

Comment: @Stefan Do you think this is the performance improvement that they are alluding to in the Ruby 2.4.0 release? c.f. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max), if n is given then maximum n elements is returned, essentially allocating array of size n as well, which is the cause of your NoMemoryError.

Comment: I believe it will allocate that much first then shrinked to the minimum (for speed reason), since n is the maximum. If the implementation doesn't take that approach, NoMemoryError won't be raised, I believe.

Comment: Yep, my guess is confirmed by https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L1701 which calls https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L1417 if n is given, where num is assigned to data.n, data.n * 4 assigned to data.bufmax, and finally data.bufmax is passed as argument to `rb_ary_tmp_new` (exception raised here).

Answer (score 0):

```
def descending_order(n)
  str_num_arr = n.to_s.chars
  str_num_arr.map(&:to_i).max(str_num_arr.length)
end
```

see rubydocs for what is passed to max, it should be an integer to return the number of items in enumerable.  Cant explain the memory error except that you've misused the method by passing a number longer than the length of enumerable.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#max